# The possessive "Have"

Tags: prepositional-phrases

We have two sentences given below:

'I have an idea in my mind'

'I have the key in my pocket'

In the above examples, what are the prepositional phrases modifying? Are they Modifying the verb phrases like:

I [have an idea] in my mind.

I [have the key] in the pocket.

Or are they adjectivally modifying  the objects of the verb 'have' as:

I have [an idea which is in my mind]

I have [the key which is in the pocket]

Although the last two don't sound good to me.

Or are there other ways of analyzing them?

Comment: It is impossible to exaggerate the importance of context in English. All we can do is assume the default. --  (i) I put the money in the bank, (ii) The money in the bank was mine. (i) is adverbial: you specified where it was put. In (ii) it is adjectival as “in the bank” distinguishes the money from all other money. -- Change the verb: "I held an idea/key in my mind/pocket". The sentence describes where you held it. It tells you nothing further about the idea/key. It is not an “in-the-mind/pocket idea/key”. It remains an undefined example of an idea. Context can change it.

Comment: It means you're saying the PPs are modifying the verb phrases. Am I right? Just got curious after someone said the PPs are modifying the objects of the verb "have" but didn't say how.

Comment: I am saying that **absent context**, the default is to assume that the PPs act adverbially. -- Consider "*I have two keys: the key in my pocket and the key in my hand*." Here, there is context and we can see that both PPs are adjectival - the keys are described, not the possession. -- "*Just got curious after someone said*." Unfortunately, I don't know who said it or why or what the context was.

Comment: I didn't give him any other context. Just those two sentences and he said the PPs are object modifiers.